# Controller does not work in route

Tags: angularjs

I would like to add link with controller to route but controller does not work. 
[image]
I get this:

> {{title}}
>
> {{shortTitle}}
>
> {{text}}

If I will put controller only to html also does not work

[image]

but when I added script to main controller in Default.html controller working correct[image]
Where I made mistake?

@SSH this not work

```
$stateProvider
.state('home', {
    url: '/',
    template: '<div data-ng-include="&#39;Scripts/js_angular_project/website/home/homePage.html&#39;"></div>',
    controller: 'homeCtrl'
})
```

homePage.html

```
<div>
    <h2>{{title}}</h2>
    <h3>{{shortTitle}}</h3>
    <p>{{text}}</p>
</div>
<script>
    app.controller('homeCtrl', function ($scope) {
        $scope.title = "Volvo";
        $scope.shortTitle = "Volvo";
        $scope.text = "example";
    });
</script>
```

@SSH this also does not work

```
 $stateProvider
    .state('home', {
        url: '/',
        templateURL: '/Scripts/js_angular_project/website/home/homePage.html',
        controller: 'homeCtrl'
    })
```

homePage.HTML - I remove ng-controller

```
<div>
    <h2>{{title}}</h2>
    <h3>{{shortTitle}}</h3>
    <p>{{text}}</p>
</div>
<script>
    app.controller('homeCtrl', function ($scope) {
        $scope.title = "Volvo";
        $scope.shortTitle = "Volvo";
        $scope.text = "example";
    });
</script>
```

@SSH this not work when I put my code

[image]

.html

[image]

Comment: I dont think that is possible, why do you need to it?

Comment: [Please do not post images of code or data as they are difficult to read](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/2873538).

Comment: you should put controller name in ui-router

Comment: @SSH if I use template as viewPart this not work controller:"homeCtrl"

Comment: you should remove `ng-controller = "homeCtrl" ` from template then it works.

Comment: @SSH also does not work. I added code to my post

Comment: try use templateUrl instead of template.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```js
var routerApp = angular.module('routerApp', ['ui.router']);
routerApp.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
    
    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/home');
    
    $stateProvider
        .state('home', {
            url: '/home',
            template: '<div><h2>{{title}}</h2><h3>{{shortTitle}}</h3><p>{{text}}</p></div>',
            controller:'homeCtrl'
        })
        .state('about', {
            url: '/about',
             template: '<div><h2>{{title}}</h2><h3>{{shortTitle}}</h3><p>{{text}}</p></div>',
             controller:'aboutCtrl'
            })
});

routerApp.controller('homeCtrl', function ($scope) {
        $scope.title = "Volvo";
        $scope.shortTitle = "Volvo";
        $scope.text = "example";
    });
    
    routerApp.controller('aboutCtrl', function ($scope) {
        $scope.title = "Volvo2";
        $scope.shortTitle = "Volvo2";
        $scope.text = "example2";
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-ui-router/0.2.10/angular-ui-router.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="routerApp">
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse" role="navigation">
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li><a ui-sref="home">Home</a></li>
        <li><a ui-sref="about">About</a></li>
    </ul>
</nav>

<div class="container">
    <div ui-view></div>
</div>
</div>
```

you should put controller name in router and also remove `ng-controller = "homeCtrl"` from template.

```
   state('home' ,{
      url : '/',
      templateUrl:'/yourTempalteAddress',
      controller:'homeCtrl' 
    })
```

and define your app in controller.

```
    var app = angular.module("yourApp",[]);
    app.controller('homeCtrl', function ($scope) {
     $scope.title = "Volvo";
     $scope.shortTitle = "Volvo";
     $scope.text = "example";
     });
```

Comment: sorry use `templateUrl` instead of `templateURL`

Comment: var app was created in parent controller var app = angular.module('authorizeSample', [
  'ui.router',
])

Comment: nothing - but homePage is partial when I wrtite this in tamplete I get text template: '<div data-ng-include="&#39;Scripts/js_angular_project/website/home/homePage.html&#39;"></div>',

Comment: please check my sample.

Comment: :) Thanks for a lot of information. This was good example many ways to fix issue.