# Getting AngularJS ui router templates error

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

I have the following routes:

```
    $stateProvider
    .state('access', {
        abstract: true,
        url: '/access',
        templateUrl: 'login.html'
    })
    .state('access.signin', {
        url: '/signin',
        templateUrl: 'tpls/signin.html',
        data: {
            authorizedRoles: [USER_ROLES.all]
        }
    });

$urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/access/signin');
```

Then my project looks something like this:

[image]

AS you can see I have a template called "`login.html`" this template looks like this:

```
<div class="logo">
    <a href="index.html">
        <img src="./assets/pages/img/logo-big.png" alt=""/> </a>
</div>
<!-- END LOGO -->
<!-- BEGIN LOGIN -->
<div class="content" ui-view>
</div>
```

However when I run this it loads the index.html as my template and doesn't use this `login.html`

What have I done wrong, and why might this be happening?

Comment: For template you don't need include js and css files. and also don't need `ng-app` and .... this  template is similar to index.html file. see [this sample](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39445949/controller-does-not-work-in-route/39446042#39446042) and [this sample](http://plnkr.co/edit/BjIEXXGt7Akh0LuplPFv?p=preview)

Comment: @Hadi ive udated my question

Comment: @Hadi what i am looking for is to change the layout completely. So that none of the html that is in index.html will be shown

Comment: You should use `ui-view` in index.html. Try checking the template path.

Comment: So use multiple views for this issue. see [this](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Multiple-Named-Views)

Comment: @hadi that worked thanks can you post it as an answer+

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you ask in your question to have multiple layouts in your app, so for this you should use ***Multiple Named Views***.

```
 $stateProvider     
 .state('report', {     
   views: {     
   'filters': { ... templates and/or controllers ... },     
   'tabledata': {},     
   'graph': {},     
  }     
})
```

For more information about it read it's [document](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Multiple-Named-Views).